# How do I isolate calcium from calcium carbonate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have the ability to use many kinds of reactions, and the use of most common acids/bases.

Comment: An easy method is to add vinegar to the calcium carbonate to remove the carbonate and get calcium acetate (in solution). What do you want to use the calcium for?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is you cannot do it almost for sure.

To obtain $\ce{Ca}$ metal from $\ce{Ca (+II)}$, you need to perform a reduction process. For this purpose, you would need a **very** strong reducing agent, because calcium is very close to the bottom in the [Ellingham diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellingham_diagram#Thermodynamics) (used in metallurgy for this same purpose: obtain metals from its salts).

So you will need to perform an electrolysis of molten calcium chloride, which is not cheap, and by any reason not doable at home or at an standard lab (just a quick view of calcium salts melting point will give you a hint about why is this...)